# Asymptotic distribution of a method of moment estimator via the delta method

Tags: probability, self-study, mathematical-statistics

Let $X_1,...,X_n$ be a random sample from X with a Beta distribution $B(\theta; 2)$, with $\theta > 0$, i.e. :
\begin{align*}
    f(x,\theta) = \theta(\theta+1)x^{\theta-1}(1-x) \mathbb{I}_{0<x<1}
\end{align*}
I found the method of moment estimator for $\theta$ :
\begin{align}
    \hat{\theta}_{M} = - \frac{2\bar{X}}{\bar{X}-1} 
\end{align}
And I now wish to find an asymptotic distribution for this estimator.

By the CLT, I have that :
\begin{align*}
    \sqrt{n}(\bar{X}-\mu) \xrightarrow{D} \mathcal{N}(0,Var(X))
\end{align*}
And I know that :
\begin{align}
    Var(X) &= \frac{\theta(\theta+1)}{(\theta+2)(\theta+3)} - \frac{\theta^2}{(\theta+2)^2} \\
    &= \frac{2\theta}{(\theta+2)^2(\theta+3)}
\end{align}
Therefore using the delta method :
\begin{align}
    \sqrt{n}(g(\hat{\theta}) -g(\theta)) \xrightarrow{D} \mathcal{N}(0,(g'(\theta))^2 \sigma^2(\theta) ) 
\end{align}
Let :
\begin{align}
    g(x) &= \frac{-2x}{x-1} \\
    \frac{dg}{dx} &= \frac{2}{(x-1)^2}
\end{align}
I therefore obtain the following asymptotic distribution for the estimator $\theta$ :
\begin{align}
\sqrt{n} (\hat{\theta} - \theta_0) \xrightarrow{D} \mathcal{N}\Bigg(0,\Big(\frac{2}{\theta-1}\Big)^2 \frac{2\theta}{(\theta+2)^2(\theta+3)} \Bigg)
\end{align}
Am I applying the delta method correctly ?

Comment: You lost the square in the denominator of $g'(x)$ in transferring to the last line

Comment: you mean it should be $\frac{4}{(\theta-1)^2} $ ?